# Incrementing variable in Bash -sed command

Tags: bash, awk, sed, auto-increment

I have a bash script that I'm trying to put together that finds all of the images in a folder and then puts the names of those files into a pre-formatted CSV.  I actually have the more complicated parts of it figured out and working well... I'm stuck on a really basic part.  I have a variable that I need to increment for each file found, simple enough right?  I've tried a bunch of different things and cannot for the life of me get it to increment. Here's the script I'm working with:

EDITED to show less context

```
i=0
find "$(pwd)" -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec file {} \; | awk -F: '{if ($2 ~/image/) print $1}' | grep -o -E '[^/]*$' | sed -e "s/^/$((++i))/" > "$(pwd)/inventory-$(date +%Y%m%d)-$(date +%I%M).csv"
```

I've tried incrementing it with `i++`, `i=+1`, `i=i+1` as well as putting the dollar sign before the different iterations of the i variable... nothing seems to actually increment the variable.  My best guess is that this isn't a true loop so it doesn't save the changes to the variable?  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please make your example more minimal by reducing it to show only the problem instead of all the context around it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really not super familiar with Bash and I didn't want to cut out parts that were relevant, I think I've cut it down now to where you'll see the part that I'm struggling with without taking out too much of the context of where this is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

The `$((++i))` is performed by your shell. But the shell executes this line only once. This line cannot do what you need.

I would increment in inside `awk`, print it alongside the file name, and then combine output in the further commands.